# Loading module with root privilages

Tags: android-ndk

I have a module developed in NDK.  The code inside the module does things (i.e, trying to open a device driver using *open* system call) which need root privilege.  The module is packaged and loaded as part of the APK.

The android app which is trying to use the NDK function fails with 'Permission denied' error.  This is because the module / app does not have root privilege.

Is it possible to load the module with root privilege?  If yes, how?

Thanks for all the contributors in advance.
Naidu

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to write your own executable and call it from your android app using su.  How to write your own executable is available in my [personal blog](http://www.btrnaidu.com/index.php/building-own-executable-in-android/).

Answer (score 0):

If your device version is < 3.0, run the command after connecting device with your pc -

```
cmd:>adb remount
cmd:>adb push <your apk file name> /system/app
cmd:>adb shell
#reboot
```

Your application will be installed after getting restarted.

Comment: I think the answer is not in the context.  Can you help me understand if I miss interpreted it?

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to keep app in system folder which will run as a system app?

Comment: The android app which is trying to use the NDK function fails with 'Permission denied' error. This is because the module / app does not have root privilege.

Is it possible to load the module with root privilege? If yes, how?

Comment: It is not possible to open device driver as a third party. You will always get permission denied error for accessing any system module, You need root permission to handle it. And you can do it according to my instruction.